# Login as another user in salesforce via API

Tags: grant-login-access, summer-15

I know there is new feature introduced in summer 15 release that Admin user can log in as another user in SF, However I want to achieve this via Partner API. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use System.runAs(user) to test your code's behavior from another user's perspective.

Comment: Thanks Dave! It looks like that is available in apex code itself, I am looking for a solution via partner API but not able to find anything related to it.